# Connecting via Ethernet VNC

Tags: ethernet, pi-4, vnc

So until now, I've been using VNC to connect to my raspberry pi 4 with my raspberry pi 4 being allocated an IP address through my router.

Now I need to be able to connect to it via ethernet cable. So I've connected an ethernet cable to my laptop and my raspberry and now I'm trying to connect to my raspberry from my laptop using the ethernet cable connected to both ends, but the connection is insanely slow.

I just can't do anything. I click something, it freezes and sometimes the VNC connection drops too and it says "attempting to connect back to the VNC server".
So what's the deal? In my mind, it should be even faster if it doesn't have to go through the router, but now it's basically impossible to use.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=161194

Comment: It is unlikely that the router will impact on the communication speed - the Pi can't keep up with Gigabit Ethernet. The problem you are experiencing is likely because you are using a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address). You should assign a Static address If you intend to pursue this, but this needs to take account of the routing. You need to explain your setup.

Comment: I assume that you usually connect to your internet router by wifi to use VNC on this path. When additional direct wired connected to the laptop then please execute these two commands and paste its output into the question, using the [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/107080/edit) link: `ip addr` and `ip route`.